# Getting String value of Dynamic SQL into Select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, dynamic, return-value, dynamic-sql

I need to reach a **return value** from Dynamic SQL. I execute select query as string with *sp_executesql*. I have to reach results. Here is sql query:

```
DECLARE @dynsql nvarchar(max)  
SET @dynsql = 'select @InvoiceNo=InvoiceNo from '+ QUOTENAME(@DynDB) +'.[dbo].[TableName] where UserID = '+ 
        cast(@UserID as nvarchar) 
EXEC sp_executesql @dynsql
```

Problem: This **@dynsql** is string value and I have to reach a value in this sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is:

We can add our **output parameter** to query then we should add it to execute line like this:

```
DECLARE @dynsql nvarchar(max)  
SET @dynsql = 'select @InvoiceNo=InvoiceNo from '+ QUOTENAME(@DynDB) +'.[dbo].[TableName] where UserID = '+ 
        cast(@UserID as nvarchar) 
EXEC sp_executesql @dynsql, N'@InvoiceNo int OUTPUT',@InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo OUTPUT
select @InvoiceNo as InvoiceNo
```

And the result is: **InvoiceNo = 11111** (int value)

Comment: This is awesome.